# Describe the desired features of a "Mathematics Colloquium"?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, terminology, math-communication, conferences

I'm now a member of my department's colloquium committee.  Our task is to make a great colloquium series. I thought that the first step would be to come up with an appropriate definition of "Mathematics Colloquium." Standard dictionaries are not too much help:

```
Colloquium: n. 
 1. A usually academic meeting at which specialists deliver
    addresses on a topic or related topics and then answer questions relating to them.
 2. A conference at which scholars or other experts present papers on, analyze, 
    and discuss a specific topic.
```

So here's my question: What is the ideal definition of a mathematics colloquium?  Of course I know a bunch of things that make for **bad** colloquium talks, so I'm interested in knowing the definition of a good or great mathematics colloquium.

Comment: See Lesson 1 in Gian Carlo Rota's 10 lessons http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~cahn/life/gian-carlo-rota-10-lessons.html#lecturing

Comment: Luke: are we interested in a definition that is an ideal to aspire to, or a description of what _actually_ happens? And what geographical variations are you or aren't you interested in?

Comment: For instance, in some places there aren't time or resources to run separate seminars for separate specialisms, so one might invite speakers to a "department colloquium" with an agreement between the various divisions that everyone gets their turn to have "their" speaker say something slightly technical

Comment: Ideally, a mathematically colloquium is like as seminar, with two differences: 1) Speakers are usually more renowned and experienced; it is often (especially) hard to give a good colloquium talk if you just start out in a field. 2) A colloquium talk should be more accessible than a seminar talk; ideally to every math faculty member (or grad student), in practice at least 70% should be understandable to at least 70% of the faculty. If condition (2) is violated repeatedly, only specialists will continue to attend colloquium and the colloquium culture has died.

Comment: I recommend the article [How to give a good colloquium](http://www.ams.org/profession/leaders/workshops/gcoll.pdf), which has advice for both speakers, the audience, and organizers.

Comment: @Jeremy, that article is pretty good. Only one I disagree with is "don't use an overhead projector" (well, data projector nowadays).

Comment: My experience is that if you manage to convince the speaker to prepare a talk for an audience of non-mathematicians, then it will be a perfect talk for mathematicians who are not experts in the field.

Comment: My advice for colloquium speakers, is to target 1st year graduate students in the audience.

Comment: For something I found on my homepage, see here: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~cremling/misc/colloquium.html

Comment: A relevant question http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/40260/12871

Comment: I'm not sure the notion of ideal colloquium should be well defined in general, but will depend upon the department.  It should, of course, fill some need not covered by usual seminar series, but the kind of audience and their expectations (both in practice and in principle) may vary from department to department.  (That said, I agree with many of the comments, but I question the existence of a universal answer to this question as stated.)

Comment: Yemon: I'm interested in a definition to strive to attain. And due to budget constraints, the quality/prestige of the speaker should increase sharply as the distance from my university increases in order to justify the cost.

Comment: A former department chair of mine used to say that if you asked colloquium speakers to prepare talks appropriate for undergraduates, then there was a chance some of the faculty would understand.

Comment: @LukeOeding, I edited your title to reflect (to my understanding) your intentions. Please do revert if I've misrepresented your intention...

Answer (score 4):

A great mathematics colloquium is one which satisfies many if not all of its goals, and may have additional benefits which make it great.

A list of potential goals/benefits:

- accessibility: many if not all attendees can understand a talk
- entertainment: attendees enjoy or find the presentation enjoyable
- breadth: the collection of topics covers a wide range of interests
- thematic: there is a common thread or other connection which relates the
  different talks and draws connections
- stimulating: encourages audience members to discuss and extend the subject matter
  outside the colloquium
- durable:  the recording made is archive quality and can be shared with others
- effective: members of the audience can take some of the main ideas and recapitulate them for others who were not at the colloquium, and make the others understand the ideas.

Of the list above, I value being effective more highly than the other items.

Gerhard "What Are Your Colloquium Goals?" Paseman, 2015.06.07

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- Let all faculty members in turn choose speakers to invite.
  This ensures that everybody gets involved, and that the interests
  of all faculty members are represented.
- Choose a room / building in which people feel well
  (this is underestimated sometimes!), and choose a time where people
  have time to attend and do not need to rush to their lectures
  once the talk is over.
- After the colloquium talks, always have a joint lunch / coffee / supper
  (depending on the time of the day) in some pub / restaurant etc..
  This fosters discussion among faculty members working on different
  fields, and with the speakers. Try to choose a different location for this
  every time.
- As others have already said, tell speakers to give talks
  which all faculty members can understand -- and not only
  specialists in the respective field.